# Errors trying to compile TypeScript compiler

Tags: typescript

I just got TypeScript source code using `git pull` and tried to [compile as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12937590/340760). But then I get lots of this error

```
'new T[]' cannot be used to create an array. Use 'new Array<T>()' instead.
```

Is that the right way to compile? Is `new T[]` a new feature and I need the latest compiler to compile the compiler?

How should I compile TypeScript projects?

Comment: have a look here https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Known%20breaking%20changes%20between%200.8%20and%200.9

looks like the bit about arrays applies. Actually I think you have it backwards, new T[] is being deprecated.

Comment: @JohnFaulkner ok, so is it normal to have breaking code over there? I never joined a big project like this before, I am trying to understand how this process works.

Comment: according to that documentation, yes, they are deprecating some things they in favor of stronger typing. I guess they previously had been less stringent, and changed their mind. That's how it reads.

Comment: Typescript is evolving pretty quickly.  Compiling the compiler isn't terribly useful, and was already done, let it lose on your own code.  Best to get started from the [stable 0.9.0.1 release](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) instead of the ever-changing github branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. I was getting errors because I was at the `master` branch which is broken.

My steps:

1. Clone `git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/typescript`
2. [Switch to develop branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72156/340760) `git checkout -b develop origin/develop`
3. [Installed node.js](http://nodejs.org/)
4. Installed Jake (`npm install -g jake`)
5. Compile (`jake local` on project's root folder)

I replaced the new compiled files on the compiler folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript
```

And ran `tsc test.ts`, and it worked.

<sub>Note: The develop branch compiles, but it is definitely not stable, beware.</sub>

Comment: Even simpler: install Node.js, and `npm install typescript`. YMMV (it's not always worth it to work on the bleeding edge - edges cut!)